# "No module named urllib2" after installed "urllib2" using pip in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: beautifulsoup, visual-studio-2015, python-3.4

I have installed "urllib2" using pip by interface in Visual Studio 2015, but the debugger gets the error in line "import urllib2".

I have solved by now using:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
   html_doc = response.read()
gp = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
```

My job is just to parse an html page. Should those two lines be fine anyway? (I'm using BeautifulSoup4 with Python 3.4.3)

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered, [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) has been split up into `urllib.request` and `urllib.error` in Python 3.

You can change your import to:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

Your code looks fine to me.